# C#: Why do I have to use the public access modifier in class's vars?

Tags: c#, oop, class, public, access-modifiers

OK, well, I **am** a beginner, so.. yeah, this may be a very stupid question.
I read that if I declare variable or object, without mentioniong the access-modifier (public, private, etc.) than it's automatically making it having the **Internal** acess modifier (and it will exist anywhere in the current namespace).

So why do I need to set my vars in a class as Public to get them in another class (such as my program's class of course).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the default is private, not internal.

Comment: the default for top level types is internal

Comment: @Captain Comic: He said variables/objects, so he's probably referring to fields, not types.

Comment: @Captain Comic, The summarized question was, specifically: "So why do I need to set my vars in a class as Public to get them in another class (such as my program's class of course)."

Comment: Yeap, and I was trying to say that he (question author) probaly read about types

Comment: Aside: you mention "vars", by which I assume you mean "fields". Fields *shouldn't* be exposed - they should be `private`. If you want to expose the data, use a *property*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you can not read? Ok, joking aside. You said you are a eginner, so this is totally normal to overlook small things.

> I read that if I declare variable or object, without mentioniong the access-modifier (public, 
>   private, etc.) than it's automatically making it having the Internal acess modifier

Ah, no. It defaults to *private*, *NOT* to internal. It defaults to the most sensible default, and internal would still allow a lot of cross class accesses that lead to bad code practices.

Comment: Thank you so much!
I read it again in a book, and the writer DID say it's Internal, but oh well. thanks for the help

Comment: Ah, here we go. Rule one: Books are not perfect. At least fal back to the official documenatation ;)

Comment: @Ken I have some curiosity to know what is that book?

Comment: I'd also add that public allows you use those classes in other assemblies. Internal is "global" within the assembly.